# Closing a terminology question as primarily opinion-based vs. writing an answer explaining why it is primarily opinion-based?

Tags: discussion, on-topic

If a terminology question asks about a subjective term, is it preferable to close it as primarily opinion-based or to write an answer explaining why it is  primarily opinion-based?

Example: [What is the difference between artificial intelligence and machine intelligence?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/262753/12359)

> I have read the term "machine intelligence" in a few places, e.g.
>   https://web.archive.org/web/20170219022131/https://research.google.com/pubs/MachineIntelligence.html:
>
> > Research at Google is at the forefront of innovation in Machine Intelligence, with active research exploring virtually all aspects of
> >     machine learning, including deep learning and more classical
> >     algorithms.
>
> What is the difference between artificial intelligence and machine
>   intelligence?
>
> I'm not sure if machine intelligence is a rebranding of artificial
>   intelligence, machine learning, or if it means something else.

Comment: I think the example question is on topic and not opinion-based (in principle). If a term is ill-defined, then one can post an answer explaining that it's ill-defined.

Comment: The question sounds fine to me.

Comment: I think the question would be a better fit for another site, the [ai.SE] SE site seems most appropriate, & is borderline on topic here. That said, in answer to your explicit question, if a Q asks for the definition of a term, that turns out to be opinion-based / subjective, it would be best to have an answer that explains that, rather than closing the thread.

Comment: In the absence of a language academy which prescribes what is English and what is not surely any question about the meaning of terminology is a matter of opinion?

Comment: @mdewey Usually not.  The test of whether something is just opinion rests on the evidence that can be brought to bear.  In the present case, one can imagine a study of recent uses of "AI" and "MI" showing exactly how these terms are used and by which communities.  The possibility of such a study--whether it has or even could be done--tells us this is not necessarily a matter of opinion.

Comment: Which of the above statements is factually correct and not an opinion?  Isn't  most of statistics opinion based anyway as proven by the many and recent huge public failures?